# PHP files on Google cloud storage without AppEngine

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to link php files on Google cloud storage, but getting them as plain text. I want to connect to the other file but without App Engine, all the documentation of this is written exclusively for app engine and can't even find if bucket storage has php support even tho it should. Any clue of how to link a PHP file correctly on Cloud Storage?

Comment: php is server side so I dont think cloud storage will execute the php file without app engine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google cloud storage is [storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/use-cases/) service which can store your object(files) and return when you ask for it.Files like HTML,JavaScript and CSS that render inside browser can be placed on google cloud storage to get performance in loading time.But in your php file need  execution engine to run it code.Placing them on storage and accessing will get to file context.